# jQuery Selector within a div

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Hi I am new to jQuery.

I have the following HTML block:

```
<html>
<body>
    <p>Paragraph1</p>
    <p>Paragraph2</p>
    <div id = "mydiv">
        <p>Paragraph3</p>
        <p>Paragraph4</p>
    </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

If I do $("p"), then this will select every paragraph. But how do I just select all the paragraphs within "mydiv"

thanks!

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: Time taken to lookup the documentation is much less than compiling a question. [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Or you can do :

```
$('#mydiv').find('p')
```

Answer (score 7):

All you have do do is this:

```
$('#mydiv p')
```

Comment: Just to note that, unlike `find` or context selector, this selector can fully benefit from the DOM QSA performance boost. And I personally consider this one the easiest to understand, seeing as anyone with an extremely basic CSS selectors understanding will be able to follow.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the context

```
$('p','#mydiv') // equal to $('#mydiv').find('p')
```

Or

```
$('#mydiv p')
```

Comment: is there anything special about the context form?

Comment: @LiviuT. Nope.. it's really useful when you have to use `this` though.. instead of writing `$(this).find('whatever')`.. you can just write `$('whatever',this)`

Answer (score 1):

```
$( "#mydiv p" )
```

Enjoy!  You can cascade selectors like this.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#mydiv p")
```

You can also use this:

```
$("#mydiv > p")
```

Another way is to define the context:

```
$('p', '#mydiv");
```